# React Native Textinput: is there a way to animate the placeholder up to being a label?

Tags: react-native, textinput, react-native-textinput

I'm using `TextInput` in my React Native app. I want to have text as a placeholder that animates up to being a top left label when the user clicks on the TextInput. The `Company Name` label in the image below shows the kind of "top left" label that I want. Are there any components in React Native, whether it's the native `TextInput` or something else, that does this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not part of the base library, but the [TextInput in react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/text-input.html) does what you want.